# react componentDidMount() Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: reactjs

hi everyone i'm kind new to react, but not sure why i'm getting error of componentDidMount() { Unexpected token, expected ";"

```
Failed to compile.

./src/layouts/pages/live.js
 Line 55:23:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
  53 |   };
  54 | 
> 55 |   componentDidMount() {
     |                       ^
  56 |     this.initLocalStream();
  57 |     this.initClient();
  58 |   }
```

and here is my code:-

```
const Live = () => {
const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
  streamID: USER_ID,
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  screen: false
});
state = {
remoteStreams: []
};
componentDidMount() {
 this.initLocalStream();
 this.initClient();
}
```

i made research about this but didn't found any usefull things to solve this, any helps and suggestions are heartly thank you,

Comment: `componentDidMount` is only available in a class component; this looks to be a function component. Use `useEffect` to get the equivalent of `componentDidMount`

Comment: hi @lux thank you for your response, i tried with `useEffect` but still same unexpected error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as below

```
const Live = () => {
const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
  streamID: USER_ID,
  audio: true,
  video: true,
  screen: false
});

//state cant' be use in functional component please remove it
state = {
remoteStreams: []
};

useEffect(()=>{
  initLocalStream();
  initClient();
},[])
\\
```

Comment: is their anything similar to componentDidUpdate? coz i have code like this `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.channel !== this.props.channel && this.props.channel !== "") {
      this.joinChannel();
    }
  }` and getting error same.

Comment: yes you can use useEffect depends on prop or state which you updated refer this link for more info

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects